# How to hide the label whenever I select the spinner value Normal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

1. Hide the label whenever I select spinner value normal

   ```
   import kivy
   kivy.require('1.10.0')
   from kivy.core.window import Window
   from kivy.app import App
   from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
   from kivy.uix.label import Label
   from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
   from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
   from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

   Window.size = (500, 400)
   Window.clearcolor = (0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2)


   def show_selected_value(spinner, text):
       print('Selected Process', spinner, 'have text', text)


   class LRefConfigAutomation(App):
       config = None

       def build_config(self, config):
           config.setdefaults('LefConfigWindowSection', {
               'PartInputLabel': 'Please Enter your Part No',
               'TypeOfProcessLabel': 'Select Type Of Process',
               'NormalFolderName': 'Enter Normal Folder Name',

           })
           self.config = config

       def build(self):
           config = self.config
           root = FloatLayout()
           lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'PartInputLabel')
           self.label = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .90}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0), halign="left",
                              valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
           self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
           self.label.font_size = '14.5dp'  # something that'll give texture bigger than phone's screen size
           root.add_widget(self.label)
           with self.label.canvas:
               Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
               Rectangle(pos=self.label.pos, size=self.label.size)
           self.txtKemNo = TextInput(pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .90}, size_hint=(None, None),
                                     font_name="Georgia", size=(100, 30), multiline=False, hint_text="Part Number")
           root.add_widget(self.txtKemNo)
           lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'TypeOfProcessLabel')
           self.label = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .75}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0), halign="left",
                              valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
           self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
           self.label.font_size = '14.5dp'  # something that'll give texture bigger than phone's screen size
           root.add_widget(self.label)
           with self.label.canvas:
               Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
               Rectangle(pos=self.label.pos, size=self.label.size)
           self.requestsspinner = Spinner(
               # default value shown
               text='Select Process',
               # available values will be binded to the combo
               values=("Normal", "Official"),
               # just for positioning in our example
               size_hint=(None, None),
               size=(110, 20),
               pos_hint={'center_x': .66, 'center_y': .75}, font_name='Georgia')
           self.requestsspinner.font_size = '14.5dp'
           self.requestsspinner.bind(text=show_selected_value)
           self.requestsspinner.bind(text=self.CreateLable)
           root.add_widget(self.requestsspinner)
           return root

       def CreateLable(self, spinner, text):
           config = self.config
           if text == "Normal":
               self.label = Label(text="", pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .65}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0),halign="left", valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
               print("Label", self.label.text)
               self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
               self.label.font_size = '14.5dp'
               self.root.add_widget(self.label)
           elif text == "Official":
               lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'NormalFolderName')
               self.label = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .65}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0),halign="left", valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
               self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
               self.label.font_size = '14.5dp'
               self.root.add_widget(self.label)


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       LRefConfigAutomation().run()
   ```

Comment: https://github.com/BollamReddy-Python-Vba/python/blob/master/Hide%20Label

Comment: I have added the code Please check

Comment: i want to hide the label, whenever i click on the spinner value "Normal"